# User's Last Activity storing in gridview using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

ID (int)

UserName (varchar)

LastActivityDate (DateTime)

TimeCreated (DateTime)

TImeModified(DateTIme)

the above information is describing my database table fields..... I have designed a gridview which is described as bellow..

Name         Lastactivity

I want to display the lastactivity data like as bellow

UserName                       lasactivity

xyz                                       now

abc                                    3 minutes ago

jim                                       3 days ago

mike                                  2 months ago

kiron                                        last year

Any one can Help me.......

Answer (score 0):

I think the datediff() function of sql should work!

Comment: according to my database structure, I can't use the datediff(). I have to work it programmatically...